# Pagination issue while sorting based on last modified property

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, pagination

I need to show some records sorted based on modified column (latest activity on top)
(Post with new edit or comments at the top)

App UI has twitter like 'more' post button for infinite scroll. each 'more' will add next 10 records to UI.

Issue is that pagination index breaks when any of the to be shown record is modified

for example 
Suppose i have records `A,B,C,..Z` in jobs table.

first time I'm' showing the records `A-J` to the user using

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

second time if none of the records are modified

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 10, 10
```

will return `K-T`

But if some body modifies any records after `J` before the user clicks 'more button',

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 10, 10
```

will return `J-S`

Here record `J` is duplicated. I can hide it by not inserting `J` to the UI, but the more button will show only 9 records. But this mechanism fails when large number of records are updated, If 10 records are modified, the query will return `A-J` again.

What is the best way to handle this pagination issue?

Keeping a second time stamp fails if a record has multiple updates.

Server cache of queries?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server, but problem is not specific to any database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a NOT IN() and a LIMIT instead of just a straight LIMIT with a pre-set offset.

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE name NOT IN('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J') 
ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 10
```

This way you still get the most recent 10 every time but you would need to be tracking what IDs have already been shown and constantly negative match on those in your sql query.

Comment: how do we handle pagination? if new records are inserted it will show in between breaking the sort order

Comment: If you are specifically tracking all the IDs that have already shown and doing a NOT IN match on those you will get a result set that is the 10 most recently updated records which are not in the first page of results. Yes it is possible that these results on page 2 will be newer than the post on page 1 but you already saw those and are negative matching on those. Basically every page is the 10 most recent updates excluding the ones already seen. It fits what you are trying to do but would potentially be a pain to manage on the code side of things.

Comment: You may can filter them by their creation time.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter timelines not paged queries they are queried by ids

This page will help you a lot understanding timeline basics https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines

lets say each column have id field too

```
id msg
1  A
2  B
....
```

First query  will give you 10 post and max post_id will be 10

Next query should be

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE id > 10 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: In twitter once processed tweets never get updated. The since_id or max_id methods will not work if some of the records to be processed on already processed get modified.

Comment: Can you explain your original question more, how you expecting to always refreshing table have pagination ?

Comment: A-Z list is the result of last modified sort query it can have the is like A[5], B[6], c[2], D[15], E[22].... So id > 10 will not work

Comment: I think i don't understand what you are doing but if i get it right, why not use last_modified instead of id ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact solution but I can give it a try.

First u need an integer ID column in your Job table.
Now send a max_id = null along with limit = 10 and offset = 0 from UI.

In this case if max_id is null, set max_id to (MAX(ID) + 1) of Table.

***SELECT (MAX(ID) + 1) INTO max_id FROM Jobs;***

Later find the records:

***SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE ID < max_id ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;***

Return the records to UI.

Now from UI set max_id = ID of first record in the response array, offset = offset + limit.

Now onwards try with updated values of max_id and offset:

***SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE ID < max_id ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;***